# I need IMU file

Tags: imu

I am developing a self-driving car using the ros2 humble.
I don't have IMU sensor now.

https://github.com/CCNYRoboticsLab/imu_tools
But I want to see if the codes on this site work properly on my computer.

Please share the IMU bag file or the site where I can get the file

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! You may have a higher chance of getting such a rosbag file while asking on [their GitHub](https://github.com/CCNYRoboticsLab/imu_tools).